# How to rename the output in operations?

Tags: permutation

The problem is the following, i have 23 Cycles, every cycle have a name:

```
f1 = Cycles[{{2, 20}, {3, 30}}]
f2 = Cycles[{{2, 3, 20, 30}}]
f3 = Cycles[{{2, 30, 20, 3}}]
...
```

But, for example if i use the operation:

```
PermutationProduct[f1, f2] 

Cycles[{{2, 30, 20, 3}}]
```

When i use the operation PermutationProduct this give me the permutation using the cycle notation, is there any way that the output of the operation gives me "f3" and not the cycle notation?. Something like this:

```
PermutationProduct[f1, f2]

f3
```

Comment: Why not set up a lookup table like `myTable = AssociationThread[{Cycles[{{2, 20}, {3, 30}}], Cycles[{{2, 3, 20, 30}}], Cycles[{{2, 30, 20, 3}}]} -> {"f1", "f2", "f3"}]; PermutationProduct[f1, f2] // myTable`?

Comment: Or if you're opposed to hash tables way just use `Select` by `Hash` (i.e. do what the hash table is doing---but do it inefficiently!)

Comment: Note that the association returns a string, so if you wanted to use the output in subsequent calculations you'd have to use `ToExpression`.